# Imagem não abre com tkinter, como resolver?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Preciso que esse código abra uma imagem em uma label, porém é retornado esse erro: "RuntimeError: Too early to create image"

```
from tkinter import *
i = PhotoImage(file="ddddd.png")
root = Tk()
label = Label(root, image=i)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

ops: O arquivo .png tá na mesma pasta do programa, to rodando o programa pelo Pycharm e python3

Answer (score 2):

Esse erro ocorre por conta de você tentar criar a imagem `i = PhotoImage(file="ddddd.png")` antes mesmo de ter criado a instância do `Tk`.

Para corrigir, é bem simples, bastar inverter a ordem das linhas da seguinte forma, primeiro o `root = Tk()` e depois a criação da imagem `i = PhotoImage(file="ddddd.png")`, ficando assim:

```
root = Tk()
i = PhotoImage(file="ddddd.png")
```

Seu código final estará mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
i = PhotoImage(file="ddddd.png")
label = Label(root, image=i)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

> **Referência:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10236857/python-tkinter-error-too-early-to-create-image

Comment: PERFEITO, funcionou, muito obrigado!!